# UI Button - activate buttons with keyboard input

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

this is probably dead easy but I can't find a solution. I made a dialogue system and have a UI-button to click when the player should display a sentence next.

The issue is that the button is only triggered onMouseclick and I would like to change the input button to Enter. Would anyone know how to go about this?

Comment: So you would like the button to NOT respond to mouse clicks and instead activate when the user hovers over it and presses the "Enter" key?

Comment: yes exactly. The mouse cursor is locked and should only be used for the gun mechanics (shooting)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to determine if the button is selected first or not, I suggest you take a look at this page: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable.IsHighlighted.html
If you don't want pressing the button to have any functionality, you just wouldn't link it to any functions.

Working code might look something like this:

```
public class selectableExample : Selectable{
BaseEventData _event;

void Update()
{
    if (IsHighlighted(_event) == true)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("enter")){
            print("replace me with working function"); // whatever you want to have happen on button press
        }
    }
}
```

}

You simply attach this to your button and it should respond the same as being pressed. To be honest, it hardly seems like you actually need a button at all for this though, you'd probably be fine with just a label telling the player to press "Enter" and then simply checking for that input.

Comment: thanks, decided to follow your instructions and not use the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Event Trigger` component to use one of the many event types. Select `Submit` (this is set to enter and return in the input settings at edit>project settings>input by default).

Don't set anything in the `OnClick` event.

The only thing needed now is to actively highlight the button from somewhere with `ReferenceToButton.Select()`.

Comment: great thank you! I tried to add an event trigger but it didnt work, probably because I've added the dialogiue manager to the Onclick event. How would I go about actively highlight the button? Do I just add an script with a public funtion and add do the trigger event?

Comment: You probably have a reference to the button somewhere right? Like for showing/hiding it? Basically you can just put that `Select()`-call there. If you show it using an event, you can add it to the public funtion for that, yes.